# Notify.js clear old notifications

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, notifications

I'm using [Notify.js](https://notifyjs.com/) to show notifications on my site.
I encountered a problem, where I add notifications show them and then, if I want to show different notification and add it as well, I see the old notifications as well.
The work flow is:

1. User input data
2. User press a button
3. Data is validated
4. Error notification added
5. Goes on until everything is correct

In order to add a notification I use the following:

```
var noteOption = {
    // whether to hide the notification on click
    clickToHide : true,
    // whether to auto-hide the notification
    autoHide : false,
    globalPosition : 'bottom right',
    // default style
    style : 'bootstrap',
    // default class (string or [string])
    className : 'error',
    // show animation
    showAnimation : 'slideDown',
    // show animation duration
    showDuration : 400,
    // hide animation
    hideAnimation : 'slideUp',
    // hide animation duration
    hideDuration : 200,
    // padding between element and notification
    gap : 10
}
var note = "My Error Message"
$.notify.defaults(noteOption);
$.notify(note, "error");
```

So now the actual question, how do I clear the notifications before adding new ones?

Thanks,
Liron

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the function you call always return a new instance of Notification
The best way is clear the old notification container:

```
$('.notifyjs-corner').empty();
```

Regretly they don't have function like: `$.singletonNotify()`

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot.

Comment: Yeah, hope it helpful

Comment: It worked like a charmed!!! Though you need to verify the classes you are using, in my case it worked with `$('.notifyjs-wrapper').remove();//clear all old notifications`. ☺

Comment: :) Yeah, it's another effective way bro

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$.notifyClose();
$.notify({...});
```

https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-notify/issues/136#issuecomment-204051563